# Alter table Laravel 5 with migration

Tags: laravel, migration

I'm making a application with laravel 5.
I change the field 'vote ' that I have defined as

```
$ table-> enum ('vote', [ '- 1 ', '0 ', '1 ']);
```

and should be as follows

```
$ table-> enum ('vote', [' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4', ' 5'] ) ;
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To do this you should follow these steps:

1. create a new migration file

   ```
   php artisan make:migration update_votes_table
   ```
2. open the newly created migration file (app_folder\database\migrations{date_migrationfile_was_created}-update_votes_tables.php)
3. change the columns you want to change

For more details see the [documentation on database migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations)

**Note:** If you add your migrations file to the question we could provide more detailed help

Comment: Per Laravel documentation: `The following column types can not be "changed": char, double, enum, (...)`. 
So, you will need to do a manual update for those column types. However that works using the `->change()` method on the migration for other simpler types.

Comment: **DON'T FORGET** to install the `doctrine/dbal` package using the Composer package manager first. Or else the proses won't success. [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#modifying-columns)

Answer (score 28):

this how i do it:

```
 php artisan make:migration Alter_votes_to_tableName --table=tableName
```

open the file and change it then

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 9):

Modifying Columns would require `doctrine/dbal` package.

1. Install the Package

   ```
   composer require doctrine/dbal
   ```
2. Create a migration

   ```
   php artisan make:migration add_values_to_vote_column_in_votes_table
   ```
3. Update the migration file

   ```
   Schema::table('votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->enum('vote', [' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4', ' 5'])->change();
   });
   ```
4. Run the migration

   ```
   php artisan migrate
   ```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#modifying-columns)

Answer (score 2):

first of all create new  migration using below command

```
php artisan make:migration Alter_your_comment_yourTableName --table=yourTableName
```

change the file as per your requirements and after that run the below command in composer

```
php artisan migrate
```